# Accuracy not improved for restored model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running an LSTM network for language modeling and I am using the `tf.Supervisor` for saving and restoring the session.

After each epoch, I print the perplexity value. The first time that I restore the session, I notice how the perplexity is lower than in the previous run, but afterwards although I see the perplexity go down in further epochs, when I restore the model the perplexity is the same as it was after the first time I saved it. 
I always print the `global_step`, so I am sure that I am loading the latest checkpoint.

Perplexity values in first run:

```
Global step 0
Epoch: 1
Train perplexity: 1053.873
Eval perplexity: 994.486
Epoch: 2
Train perplexity: 559.507
Eval perplexity: 803.345
Epoch: 3
Train perplexity: 377.886
Eval perplexity: 606.682
Epoch: 4
Train perplexity: 282.728
Eval perplexity: 472.485
Epoch: 5
Train perplexity: 229.564
Eval perplexity: 433.604
```

Second run after restore:

```
Global step 830
Epoch: 1
Train perplexity: 394.555
Eval perplexity: 562.316
Epoch: 2
Train perplexity: 280.981
Eval perplexity: 440.451
Epoch: 3
Train perplexity: 226.292
Eval perplexity: 384.905
Epoch: 4
Train perplexity: 189.826
Eval perplexity: 340.012
Epoch: 5
Train perplexity: 166.766
Eval perplexity: 328.017
```

Third run after restore:

```
Global step 1648
Epoch: 1
Train perplexity: 374.898
Eval perplexity: 508.347
Epoch: 2
Train perplexity: 271.804
Eval perplexity: 419.742
Epoch: 3
Train perplexity: 224.735
Eval perplexity: 367.012
Epoch: 4
Train perplexity: 192.667
Eval perplexity: 336.119
Epoch: 5
Train perplexity: 170.210
Eval perplexity: 303.626
```

All further runs deliver similar results, the `global_step` continues to go up, but the perplexity value stays the same.

Below a snippet of the code from where I start the session.

```py
def run_epoch(session: tf.Session, model, is_train=False, verbose=False):
    costs = 0
    costs_list = []
    iters = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    fetches = {'cost': model.cost,
               'final_state': model.final_state,
               'outputs': model.outputs,
               'states': model.states
               }

    if is_train:
        fetches.update({'train_op': model._train_op})

    state = session.run(model.initial_state)
    for step in range(model.input.epoch_size):
        feed_dict = {}
        for i, (c, h) in enumerate(model.initial_state):
            feed_dict[c] = state[i].c
            feed_dict[h] = state[i].h

        vals = session.run(fetches, feed_dict)

        cost = vals["cost"]
        state = vals["final_state"]

        costs += cost
        costs_list.append(cost)
        iters += model.input.num_steps

        if verbose and step % (model.input.epoch_size // 10) == 10:
            print('mean_cost:', np.array(costs_list).mean(), 'costs:', costs, 'iters:', iters)
            print("%.3f perplexity: %.3f speed: %.0f wps" %
                  (step * 1.0 / model.input.epoch_size, np.exp(costs / iters),
                  iters * model.input.batch_size * max(1, 1) /
                  (time.time() - start_time)))
            costs_list = []
    return np.exp(costs / iters)


def train_model():
    config = ModelConfig()
    raw_data, id_to_word = embed_to_vocab(config, TRAIN_SOURCE)
    word_to_id = {w: i for i, w in id_to_word.items()}
    raw_eval_data, id_to_word_eval = embed_to_vocab(config, EVAL_SOURCE, word_to_id=word_to_id)


    with tf.Graph().as_default():

        with tf.name_scope('train'):
            with tf.variable_scope('Model'):
                data_input = LstmInput(config, raw_data)
                model = LstmNet(config, data_input)

        print('train model created')

        with tf.name_scope('eval'):
            with tf.variable_scope('Model', reuse=True):
                eval_input = LstmInput(config, raw_eval_data)
                eval_model = LstmNet(config, eval_input, is_training=False)

        print('eval model created')

        config_proto = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=False)
        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=SAVE_PATH, save_model_secs=7)

        with sv.managed_session(config=config_proto) as session:
            print('Global step', sv.global_step.eval(session=session))
            for i in range(EPOCHS):
                print('Epoch: %s' % (i + 1))
                train_perplexity = run_epoch(session, model, verbose=False, is_train=True)
                print('Train perplexity: {:.3f}'.format(train_perplexity))
                eval_perplexity = run_epoch(session, eval_model)
                print('Eval perplexity: {:.3f}'.format(eval_perplexity))
            print(sv.global_step.eval(session=session))
```

Comment: I'd suggest to narrow down the problem. Instead of looking at the output of the `run_epoch` it might be helpful to look at the individual values used in that calcuation. Is it cost? iter? ...

Comment: Are you using the same train/eval split on each run?

Comment: Can you try using tf.train.Saver.last_checkpoints to get the different checkpoints saved and then pass different outputs you get to the restore function and see if  some model gives expected results or if there is some ambiguity with checkpoint names?

Comment: @de1, What do you mean by iter? You can see the global step being printed out.

Comment: @ElielVanHojman at the end of your `run_epoch` function you are calculating the perplexity using multiple variables, including `costs` and `iters`. I think it would be worth reducing that method so that you can identify the variable that brings the perplexity up. It may as well be `costs`.